# Mongoose conditional update with array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Cart schema in Mongoose including CartItems as an array of objects.

```
{
  _id: string;
  items: [
    {
      product: string;
      options: {
        size: string;
        color: string;
      }
      quantity: number;
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case, is it possible to push an item when product and options doesn't match or add quantity when it does?

Here is the code that I have tried which does not work.

```
Cart.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, {
    items: {
      $cond: [
        {
          // Does not work
          $elemMatch: {
            product,
            "options.color": options.color,
            "options.size": options.size,
          },
        },
        {
          // Should add quantity where it is matched.
        },
        {
          $push: {
            product,
            productName,
            options,
            quantity,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2
- `newProduct` is the product you want to add (a js variable)
- check if product already exists => add not-exist? field
- if not-exists add it in the end
- else map to find it and update the quantity
- unset the 2 fields `newProduct` and `not-exists`

*it does 2 array reads, alternative could be to use `$reduce` but if you have many products `$concatArrays` is slow to be inside a reduce, so this is faster solutions (even if reduce would read the array 1 time only)

*you need a method to do update with pipeline, i don't know if mongoose is updated to support it, we are MongoDB 5 so i guess it will be(java is), in worst case you can use [`updateCommand`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/) and call it with `runCommand(...)`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70527186-m)

```js
update({"_id" : "1"},
[{"$set":
  {"newProduct":
   {"product":"p1",
    "options":{"size":"s1", "color":"c1"},
    "quantity":1}}},
 {"$set":
  {"not-exists?":
   {"$eq":
    [{"$filter":
      {"input":"$items",
       "cond":
       {"$and":
        [{"$eq":["$$this.product", "$newProduct.product"]},
         {"$eq":["$$this.options.size", "$newProduct.options.size"]},
         {"$eq":["$$this.options.color", "$newProduct.options.color"]}]}}},
     []]}}},
 {"$set":
  {"items":
   {"$cond":
    ["$not-exists?", {"$concatArrays":["$items", ["$newProduct"]]},
     {"$map":
      {"input":"$items",
       "in":
       {"$cond":
        [{"$and":
          [{"$eq":["$$this.product", "$newProduct.product"]},
           {"$eq":["$$this.options.size", "$newProduct.options.size"]},
           {"$eq":["$$this.options.color", "$newProduct.options.color"]}]},
         {"$mergeObjects":
          ["$$this", {"quantity":{"$add":["$$this.quantity", 1]}}]},
         "$$this"]}}}]}}},
 {"$unset":["not-exists?", "newProduct"]}])
```

---

Query2

- if you don't want to use update pipeline you can do it with more queries

**Check if exists**

```js
db.collection.find({
  "_id" : "1",
  "items": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "product": "p1",
      "options": {
        "size": "s1",
        "color": "c1"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**If not exists**

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "1"
},
{
  "$push": {
    "items": "NEWITEM"   //put here the new object
  }
})
```

**else If exists**

```js
db.collection.update({"_id" : "1"},
{
  "$inc": {
    "items.$[i].quantity": 1
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "i.product": "p1",
      "i.options.size": "s1",
      "i.options.color": "c1"
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: This is impressive. However, I feel this sort of query is too complicated to maintain.

Comment: you can do it also with more queries and not pipeline update, i added alternative way, but aggregation framework is important part of MongoDB, the first query looks bigger because of JSON syntax it looks complicated but its not so much.

Comment: My intention is to run atomically safe query which prevents manipulation between find and update. So the first one you suggested will fit my needs.